# How to unit test async code failing to fulfill

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I want to test whether an async function doesn't succeed in a certain situation but can't figure out how to do that. Previously with completion blocks, I'd do this:

```
let expectation = expectation(description: "load foo")
expectation.isInverted = true
fooManager.load {
  expectation.fulfill()
}
waitForExpectations(timeout: 1)
```

However, now my function is async/await the only thing I can do is this:

```
await fooManager.load()
```

But obviously nothing can load after the thread has been suspended, therefore I can't tell if it's failed. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a completion block wrapper:

```
private func loadWrapper(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
  Task {
    await gooManager.load()
    completion()
  }
}
```

Then in the unit test you can use the inverted expectation:

```
let expectation = expectation(description: "load foo")
expectation.isInverted = true
loadWrapper {
  expectation.fulfill()
}
waitForExpectations(timeout: 1)
```